# auto config router with rest api

Tags: python, rest, router, sdn, ryu

I have a problem in my project. It is about how to auto config router using rest api in ryu controller or improve a program with router using rest api in ryu controller.

I have tried config in a manual way but it is not the target of project. Can you help me a idea to build a program or a way to auto config router with rest api.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.